# Как расположить боки со случайной высотой средствами css?

Tags: html, css

Можно ли как-то средствами css сделать вот такое распределение блоков? В каждом из них находится контент, который имеет случайный размер. Так же важно, чтобы блоки располагались по порядку сверху-вниз. Буду благодарен любой помощи, или примеру!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можно. почитайте про grid и/или flexbox. эти технологии незаменимы (не считая решений а-ля бутстрапа) для данных вопросов. и на их изучение уйдет пол часа

Comment: _"... который имеет случайный размер ..."_ А если блок 2 будет размером с три-четыре блока, то какой должен быть порядок?

Comment: Можете предоставить html код, чтобы можно было понять кокой css писать?